# Why is the output of the homework submitting website different from Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, greatest-common-divisor

So I created a program to find out the greatest common divisor of five numbers.

And the output when I was using the visual studio is just fine, but the output on the online system becomes crazy.

Like putting 12, 24, 8, 36, 100 into the program, the output will be 32758.

Can anyone answer me?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
const int LEN = 5;
int x = 0;

// TODO 1: Complete the function declaration of GCD(), takes 2 interger as parameter.
int GCD(int n1, int n2) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n1 && i <= n2; i++) {
        if (n1 % i == 0 && n2 % i == 0) {
            x = i;
        }
    }
    return x;
}

// TODO 2: Complete the function implementation, return the GCD of 2 given number 
int main() {
    int Num[LEN];
    int answer;
    int gcd[4], y, z;
    cout << "Enter " << LEN << " numbers:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
        cin >> Num[i];
    cout << "GCD:" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i < LEN; i++) {
        gcd[i - 1] = GCD(Num[i - 1], Num[i]);
    }
    for (z = 3; z >= 0; z--) {
        if (gcd[z] < gcd[z - 1]) {
            y = gcd[z];
            gcd[z] = gcd[z - 1];
            gcd[z - 1] = y;
        }
    }
    answer = gcd[0];
    cout << answer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[The output on the online system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlaGD.png)

Comment: Write your code instead of putting pictures.

Comment: Wrote. Can you please help me i cant figure it out and i have to hand in the homework in an hour

Comment: What is the link of visual studio website that you used?

Comment: what do you mean by link? I used the visual studio 2017 application.

Comment: OK, you said you tried it on a website and found it wrong, what is this website?

Comment: The website is the submitting system of my school. It said it is using the visual studio 2017 complier

Comment: Try the `GCD` function only in the website first, it could be a problem in the website.

Comment: Enter 5 numbers:
GCD:
12
6
6
12
32759

Comment: so i try to print all the divisor compared with five numbers. And all the divisor are normal.... and the output is still strange

Comment: Show me these divisors.

Comment: numbers:12 24 6 36 60  divisor:12 6 6 12

Comment: This loop `for (z = 3; z >= 0; z--)` when `z==0` :  `gcd[z - 1]` will be Undefined Behaviour

Comment: Yeaaa my man. Got it. Just remove the  `=` at z>=0 and it sloved

Comment: The problem @RichardCritten has pointed is responsible for the large incorrect value you are getting. There is also a flaw in your algorithm that you will need to take a step back and think about what you are doing to find.

Comment: Instead of this, use my simple answer, as your algorithm will give a wrong answer for 4, 20, 5, 20, 20 for example. It will return 4 while it should be 1.

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate gcd like this, not for every two successive numbers.

```
answer = Num[0];
for (int i = 1; i < LEN; i++)
    answer = GCD(answer, Num[i]);
cout << answer << endl;
```